# $T:\Bbb Z_5^n \to\Bbb Z_5^3$, $n>1$. Prove that if $T$ is onto and $\ker T$ contains 5 vectors then $n=4$

Tags: linear-algebra

> $T:\Bbb Z_5^n \to \Bbb Z_5^3$, $n>1$. Prove that if $T$ is onto and $\ker T$ contains 5 vectors then $n=4$

This is supposed to be simple and the solution in the textbook is just a line but I couldn't  understand a certain part.

since it is onto we know that $dimImT=3$ and according to the dimension theorem $dimkerT=n-dimImT$ from here we get $dimkerT=n-3$ the following part is what I did not understand I will quote the textbook "on the other hand $dimkerT=1$ because it has 5 vectors therefore $n=4$ I cannot understand how they got to $dimkerT=1$ because it contains 5 vectors? I know this is a simple question and there isn't much to show on what I tried but I do not seem to understand it.

Thank you!

Comment: The number of vectors in a $d$-dimensional subspace over the field $\Bbb Z_p$ equals $p^d$. Do you see why this is true? Does it help you resolve the problem?

Comment: @GregMartin so for the kernel it is $5^1$ and for the image it is $5^3$? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $T$ is onto, $n-\dim\ker T=3$, that is, $\dim\ker T=n-3$. Since $\ker T$ contain only 5 vectors we get that $\dim\ker T=1$, so $n=4$.

Comment: appreciate the answer! can you please tell me how you got that $dimkerT=1$ because it has 5 vectors?

Comment: If a subspace contains a non-zero vector, then it contains all the multiples of this, that is, 5 different vectors. So the kernel is generated by only one vector.